# Linked Server Query works, but OPENQUERY of same produces error "Could not find server 'SERVER' in sys.servers

Tags: sql-server, ssms

Looking for pointers on how to resolve this issue.

I have a linked server setup. 
This query works in SSMS, I get rows back.

```
SELECT tbl.[Col1]
      ,tbl.[CoL2]
  FROM [LINKEDSERVER].[CATALOG].[SCHEMA].[TABLENAME] tbl
```

But trying to do the same in SSMS with OPENQUERY fails

```
SELECT [Col1]
FROM OPENQUERY([LINKEDSERVER],
'SELECT tbl.[Col1]
      ,tbl.[CoL2]
  FROM [LINKEDSERVER].[CATALOG].[SCHEMA].[TABLENAME] tbl'
) As Whatever
```

The messages are as follows:

> OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "SERVER" returned
>   message "Deferred prepare could not be completed.". Msg 8180, Level
>   16, State 1, Line 1 Statement(s) could not be prepared. Msg 7202,
>   Level 11, State 2, Line 1 Could not find server 'SERVER' in
>   sys.servers. Verify that the correct server name was specified. If
>   necessary, execute the stored procedure sp_addlinkedserver to add the
>   server to sys.servers.

The server name SERVER does appear when I check   `select * from sys.servers` 
OPENQUERY from here against other linked servers is successful.

Comment: Because when you use OPENQUERY you send the query you want to run on **the remote** server. The error is being thrown by the remote server. Take out the linked server in the query.

Comment: Thanks @SeanLange
To give credit where it is due..
If you put your comment as an answer i will mark it accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because when you use OPENQUERY you send the query you want to run on the remote server. The error is being thrown by the remote server. Take out the linked server name in the query. Something along these lines.

```
SELECT [Col1]
FROM OPENQUERY([LINKEDSERVER],
'SELECT tbl.[Col1]
      ,tbl.[CoL2]
  FROM [CATALOG].[SCHEMA].[TABLENAME] tbl'
) As Whatever
```

Answer (score 0):

This sentence its use with another server but , its ok try this:

1. EXEC SP_SERVEROPTION 'SERVER\INSTANCIA' ,'DATA ACCESS',TRUE
2. SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(YOURSERVER,'SELECT * FROM TABLE').

And its done. :)